# Cross validation error of Gaussian process with noisy target

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I created the Gaussian process model and trained with noisy target. I implemented the noise as a parameter alpha [n_samples] according to documentation for the last scikit-learn 18.

```
model = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel,n_restarts_optimizer=0, alpha=dy_train ** 2)
```

It works until I want to perform cross validation. It raises an error that the length of the alpha parameter and actual target is not equal:

```
scores = cross_val_score(model, X_test, y_test)
ValueError: alpha must be a scalar or an array with same number of entries as y.(35 != 10)
```

I understand the error but I don't know how to properly define alpha vector for cross validation. Please any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Alpha is supposed to be **a number** (and it would work just fine with your code). You can also have per-sample alpha, but this will not work with .cross_val_score, since it has no support for slicing internally. Furthermore what you are using looks like an extremely odd heuristic to assign alpha. I am pretty sure it is not anywhere in scikitlearn documentation. In order to use cross validation you need to go with the 'full' approach which is iterating over [cross validation iterators](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) and averaging yourself. It is pretty much three lines of code, thus should not be a big burden

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
import numpy as np

kf = KFold(n_splits=10)
scores = []
for train, test in kf.split(X):
    model.fit(X_train)
    scores.append(model.score(X_test, y_test))
print np.mean(scores)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the code. It seems to be quite easy. What do you mean "extremely odd heuristic" ? I understand the "alpha" parameter to be a noise coefficient which represents uncertainty of the target data. Since the noise variance changes per sample, the alpha parameter is the vector of standard errors. Because I am a beginner in the Gaussian process regression and machine learning, i would be grateful for any suggestion how to model Gaussian noise of output data correctly.

Comment: By extremely odd heuristic I mean setting up the alpha to be square of the target values (which you do right now - by passing dy_train ** 2) - why would you do that? I see no point unless you have some serioud insight into the data and know that this is exactly how dependent value behaves. It is **a regularization** added to semi-definite matrix estimator in training. Yes, this is related to noise, but this is way more complex and the values you provided make no sense. Alpha should be small... 1e-3 - 1e-5 might bea lready a big value and you are adding y ** 2.

Comment: I understand, but what is the correct way to implement the noisy response into GP model?